# Is there search-members helper in MailChimp v3?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I've been meaning to use MailChimp API, and since v3 is out already, I'd like to use it. I see there's a search-members helper like in v2 (https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/helper/search-members.php) and what is the endpoint for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, searching members in this way isn't supported in API v3.0.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thank you for saving me so much time! Cheers

Comment: No way to migrate to 3.0 then.  Thanks, mailchimp!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get one spesific member by email address you can use this endpoint: [Lists Members Instance](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/lists/members/lists-members-instance)

Not sure this is what you are looking for, but I was also looking for search-helper just to get one spesific user by email.

*"But hey, how it happens, I dont have members id?"*

Yes you do, if you have email address of that member you can create the id too. It's just MD5 Hash of lowercased version from that email address.

Comment: I meant more like search based on some criteria, not just get the specific member. The md5 thing helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is a search-members endpoint now on V3. I believe it was released after the original answer to this question:

http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/search-members/

In case the link should change in the future it can be found under the main V3 MailChimp API documentation under the Search Members area.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14662311)

Comment: I am not really sure what else I could have answered. The OP was saying that there was a v2 search members. The accepted answer was saying that there was not such method. I was merely saying that there is now a method and gave a link to it. I am not sure who voted my answer down but I would like to know what else I should have written that would have made it more useful!